# Are neo4j properties case sensitive?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Are neo4j properties case sensitive? In other words; are these 2 `Cypher` queries same or different:

```
MATCH (n:Person {name: "Someone"}) RETURN n;

MATCH (n:Person {name: "someone"}) RETURN n;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, property values are case sensitive. The cypher queries you have provided are different.

The following query creates two nodes:

```
create (p1:Person {name:"Someone"}), (p2:Person {name:"someone"})
```

And the following only returns one node...

```
MATCH (n:Person {name: "Someone"}) RETURN n;
```

However, you can create case insensitive indexes (assuming e.g. that `name` is part of the index). Check out the [Neo4j docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html) for more info.

Comment: small add-on to the correct answer: you can use case insensitive regex matching in a where filter - however this will not use an schema index: `MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name =~ "(?i)someone" RETURN n` should return both.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster, thanks for the update! It may be worth mentioning that if the index is not used (as in your example) a query may be very slow.

Comment: ... which depends on your amount of data ;-) If you have a huge graph but only a handful of nodes carrying the `Person` label, the regex query sketched will be reasonably fast.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster, agreed ;)